# Pytesseract not working on windows os. Subprocess.py is missing?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, tesseract

I am trying to get tesseract-ocr to recognize a string on an image. I am using python on a windows os pc. I have installed the python wrapper for tesseract-OCR i.e. pytesseract with pip install. I get the following error message:

```
runfile('C:/Users/rlc/Desktop/tesseract_test.py', wdir='C:/Users/rlc/Desktop')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input- 1-5f5eff4c4064>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/rlc/Desktop/tesseract_test.py', wdir='C:/Users/rlc/Desktop')
  File "C:\Users\rlc\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\rlc\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/rlc/Desktop/tesseract_test.py", line 12, in <module>
    pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('example_02.png'))
  File "C:\Users\rlc\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 161, in image_to_string
    config=config)
  File "C:\Users\rlc\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 94, in run_tesseract
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\rlc\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Users\rlc\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 959, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
    WindowsError: [Error 2] Den angivne fil blev ikke fundet.
```

It seems it cannot find the file   subprocess.py.

Any solutions, good ideas or a tutorial for getting tesseract-ocr working on a windows os pc? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think Anaconda2 bundles subprocess (as it is based on an older version of py2 where it wasn't available, possibly?), so try upgrading to Anaconda3 or try the most recent python.org distribution of py2 if you have to use py2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Asked a good colleague who helped me figure out what the issue was. If you are interested see the solution in my answer provided below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out that subprocess.py is actually included in both Anaconda 2 and Anaconda 3. The reason for the error was that the path where tesseract is located was not added as an environment path variable in Windows.

Steps for getting pytesseract working on windows.

1. Install Anaconda 2 or Anaconda 3 from https://www.continuum.io/downloads
2. Install tesseract for windows from http://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/tesseract-ocr-setup-4.00.00dev.exe
3. Add the tesseract directory to windows as a PATH environment variable.
4. Install pytesseract e.g.

   pip install pytesseract

and..

```
    import pytesseract
    from PIL import Image
    image = Image.open('example_02.png')
    code = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
    print code
```

voila.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this when start the scanning of a image:

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r'C:\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

text = str(pytesseract.image_to_string(filename))
print(text)
```

Note: instead of "C:\Tesseract-OCR use the actual path with \tesseract.exe of tesseract in your pc.

Here the link of tesseract latest version:

32 bit version

visit: https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/tesseract-ocr-w32-setup-v5.0.0-alpha.20191030.exe

64 bit version

visit: https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.0.0-alpha.20191030.exe